# Вывод только заданных столбцов

Tags: c#, winforms

Выводит все столбцы, нужно только два.

Код:

```
private void button8_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView6.Columns)
    {
        dataGridView5.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);     
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView4.Columns)
    {
        dataGridView5.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView6.SelectedRows)
    {
        int index = dataGridView5.Rows.Add(r.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);
        foreach (DataGridViewCell o in r.Cells)
        {
            dataGridView5.Rows[index].Cells[o.ColumnIndex].Value = o.Value;
        }
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView4.SelectedRows)
    {
        int index = dataGridView5.Rows.Add(r.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);
        foreach (DataGridViewCell o in r.Cells)
        {
            dataGridView5.Rows[index].Cells[o.ColumnIndex].Value = o.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, указав КОРРЕКТНУЮ проблему, что у вас работает не так. Предложение "выводит не те" ничего не проясняет. Чётко и понятно напишите, что вам нужно сделать, какие строки вывести и куда, с чем возникает проблема

Comment: `Выводит все столбцы, нужно только два`, в таком случае, зачем вы перебираете все через `foreach`?